# (Android) Send byte via Bluetooth to µController

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So, I want my Android Phone (4.2) to send a byte Array via Bluetooth to my µController. To achieve that I used the Bluetooth Chat example provided by Google in the SDK and modified it a bit. I have two pieces of code. One is working, one is not. Why is code 1 working while code 2 isn't? (To clarify: With code 1 I can send the byte[] to the µController)

The app crashes when pressing the send button in code 2.

Of course I could use code 1, but I want to know why code 2 is not working to avoid this error with future projects.

The differences in the code are the following:

- Code 1 sends the byte[] when a toggleButton changes its state
- Code 2 sends the byte[] when the SendButton is pressed

//Code 1

```
private void setup() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setup()");

    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    final ToggleButton TBut1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    final ToggleButton TBut2 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    final ToggleButton TBut3 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);

    final TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    final byte[] daten = new byte[1];        

    TBut1.setChecked(false);
    TBut2.setChecked(false);
    TBut3.setChecked(false);
    daten[0]=0;
    TBut1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((TBut1.isChecked() == true)){                    
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] | 4);
                mService.write(daten);                    
                }else{
                    daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~4);
                    mService.write(daten);
                }   
        }   
    });

    TBut2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((TBut2.isChecked() == true)){                    
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] | 2);
                mService.write(daten);                    
                }else{
                    daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~2);
                    mService.write(daten);
                }                   
        }   
    });

    TBut3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((TBut3.isChecked() == true)){                  
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] | 1);
                mService.write(daten);                  
                }else{                  
                    daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~1);
                    mService.write(daten);
                }                   
        }   
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mService = new BTService(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

}
```

//Code 2

```
 private void setup() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setup()"); 

    final ToggleButton TBut1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    final ToggleButton TBut2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    final ToggleButton TBut3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);

    final Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            daten[0] = 0;
            if(TBut1.isChecked()) {
                daten[0] = (byte) (daten[0] | 1);
            } else {
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~1);
            }
            if(TBut2.isChecked()) {
                daten[0] = (byte) (daten[0] | 2);
            } else {
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~2);
            }
            if(TBut3.isChecked()) {
                daten[0] = (byte) (daten[0] | 4);
            } else {
                daten[0]= (byte) (daten[0] & ~4);
            }


            if (mService.getState() == BTService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                 mService.write(daten);
            }
        }   
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mService = new BTService(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

}
```

Comment: can you show your logcat message?

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long. http://pastie.org/private/8s45ynhaoo1uiosjco1pq